# ARCore model size

Tags: java, android, google-api, frame, arcore

I'm tring to put a 3D Model into an ARCore Frame, but when I'm going to place the model it comes oversized and does not appear at the center of the screen. I don't want to place it with a tap, the app places the model automatically .

```
Anchor newMarkAnchor = session.createAnchor(frame.getCamera().getPose().compose(Pose.makeTranslation(0, 0, -0.5f)).extractTranslation());
                AnchorNode addedAnchorNode = new AnchorNode(newMarkAnchor);
                ModelRenderable.builder().setSource(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.imac).build().thenAccept(modelRenderable -> renderable = modelRenderable).exceptionally(throwable -> {Log.i("asdasdasd", "errore: "+throwable.getLocalizedMessage());
                    return null;
                });
                addedAnchorNode.setRenderable(renderable);
                addedAnchorNode.setParent(arSceneView.getScene());
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the dimensions of your model with 3D software, in ARCore 1 unit in the virtual world is equivalent to 1 meter in the real world.

Looks like you're using Sceneform, is this correct? You can scale your Node easily through `setWorldScale(Vector3)` or `setLocalScale(Vector3)`.

Comment: already tried with setWorldScale(Vector3) but does not work. yes I'm using sceneform. Any solution for make object appear in the center of the screen?

Comment: Where does your object appear? I would suggest to separate your 2 goals: first place your object at world origin (0, 0, 0) and once the size and location makes sense work on placing it in front of the camera. But do you want it to follow the camera and ALWAYS be in the center of the screen? if so, you will need to adjust its position at every frame.